# Why are the fields not separated by a whitespace in the output of this example?

Tags: text-processing, awk, gawk

When applying

```
awk -F'[,/]' '{sub(/\/[0-9]+/, "/" ($2+3) ); print $0}'
```

to input

```
Statements and Functions/399,Black,notBold
```

why is the output

```
Statements and Functions/402,Black,notBold
```

instead of

```
Statements and Functions 402 Black notBold
```

?

1. `-F'[,/]'` changes the field separator `FS` to be either `,` or `/`,
   for awk to read the input.

   `OFS` is by default a whitespace. So when `print $0`, aren't all the
   fields `$1`, ..., and `$NF` joined with separator `OFS` to create
   `$0`?
2. Change

   ```
   awk -F'[,/]' '{sub(/\/[0-9]+/, "/" ($2+3) ); print $0}'
   ```

   to

   ```
   awk -F'[,/]' '{sub(/\/[0-9]+/, "/" ($2+3) ); $1=$1; print $0}'
   ```

   will  output

   ```
   Statements and Functions 402 Black notBold
   ```

   for input

   ```
   Statements and Functions/399,Black,notBold
   ```

   Then what are all the other cases (besides assigning to a field) so that `$0`
   will be reformatted with `OFS`?
3. If a field  must be changed so that `$0` will be reformatted with
   `OFS`, then why when

   ```
   awk -F'[,/]' '{sub(/\/[0-9]+/, "/" ($2+3) ); print $0;  print $2;  print $0}'
   ```

   applies to input

   ```
   Statements and Functions/399,Black,notBold
   ```

   the output shows that the value of `$2` changes, while `$0` remains
   unaffected by `OFS`?

   ```
   Statements and Functions/402,Black,notBold
   402
   Statements and Functions/402,Black,notBold
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convince `awk` that the fields have changed to force it to reformat them with `OFS`. If you make a substitution on the whole `$0` as in your case then `awk` doesn't see the need to split it into pieces and reformat back.

You can do something like this to make it accept that things have changed:

```
awk -F'[,/]' '{sub(/\/[0-9]+/, "/" ($2+3) ); $1=$1; print $0}'
```

The `$1=$1` does the trick :)

Note that the `sub()` doesn't change `$2` - it scans and changes `$0` and updates it with the value of `$2+3`. But it doesn't update `$2`, it updates `$0` hence it doesn't trigger reformatting.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that  when  `OFS` applies to `$0` is when `$0` is reformatted? Could you list all the cases when `$0` is reformatted, besides the case when a field is assigned to?

Comment: Does `sub(/\/[0-9]+/, "/" ($2+3) )` change the value of `$2`? If yes, why does it not cause `$0` to be reformatted? If no, why is the value of `$2` in the output of `$0` increased by `3`?

Comment: @Tim it's also used when printing out individual fields, e.g. `awk -F'[,/]' 'print $1,$2,$3,$4}'`

Comment: @Tim - nope, the `sub()` doesn't change `$2`. If scans `$0` for `/[0-9]+` and replaces that with the value of `$2+3`. But it doesn't modify `$2`, it modifies `$0`, hence it doesn't trigger reformatting.

Comment: Do you mean printing out individual fields will also cause `$0` to be reformatted? If yes, the output of `awk -F'[,/]' '{for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) print $i; print $0}'` on `Statements and Functions/402,Black,notBold` is still `Statements and Functions/402,Black,notBold` instead of `Statements and Functions 402 Black notBold`.

Comment: @Tim - Printing individual fields will use `OFS` to join them, e.g. in `print $1,$2,$3,$4`. It won't cause `$0` reformat.

Comment: Thanks. Could you summarize all the cases which can cause`$0` to be reformatted so that `OFS` will apply to `print $0`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62372/discussion-between-mlu-and-tim).

Comment: My computer is too slow to use chat. Can we stay our discussion here?

Comment: @Tim 
I'll leave that to you to research, investigate and summarise all the cases ;) Now you know what happens and why. I trust I answered your original question in sufficient details and would appreciate if you could tick my answer as correct. All the best :)

Comment: I just updated my post to show that " the `sub()` doesn't change `$2`" isn't true. See my edit.

Comment: Nope, `sub()` in your case doesn't change `$2`, really. It changes `$0` and when `$2` is needed later on then `$0` string is parsed *at that point*, to get a fresh `$2`. That's how it works.

Comment: Then `$2` changes, so why hasn't `$0` changed yet? What really is the relation between updating `$0` and updating a field?

Comment: Only when `$2` is written to by *your code* it changes from `awk` perspective. If it's changed by way of changing `$0` through `sub()` it doesn't trigger reformatting because by definition `awk` already knows what `$0` is - it just used it to figure out `$2` a moment ago.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you will be better served by using:

```
awk -F'[,/]' '{$2=($2+3)}1' infile
```

with infile as this:

```
$ cat infile
The Ubiquitous Backslash/49,Black
The Ubiquitous Backslash/17,Black
Statements and Functions/399,Black,notBold
```

You will get:

```
$  awk -F'[,/]' '{$2=($2+3)}1' infile
The Ubiquitous Backslash 52 Black
The Ubiquitous Backslash 20 Black
Statements and Functions 402 Black notBold
```

HTH